# Parallel algorithm that does a small insertion/shifting

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

Say I have a array A of 8 numbers, I have another array B of numbers to determine how many places should the number in A be shifted to right

A     3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5

B     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

0 means valid, 1 means this number should be 1 place after, the output array is should insert 0 between after 3, the output array C should be :

C: 3,0,6,7,8,1,2,3

Whether to insert 0 or something else is not important, the point is that all numbers after 3 got shifted by one place. The outbound numbers will not be in the array anymore.

Another example:

A     3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5

B     0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0

C     3, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2

.......................................

A     3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5

B     0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0

C    3, 0, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3

I am thinking about using scan/prefix-sum or something similar to solve this problem. also this array is small that I should be able to fit the array in one warp (<32 numbers) and use shuffle instructions. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I think you have some ambiguity in your examples.  Suppose in the last example I use `B 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`, is the output (`C`) any different?  If not, what should the output array look like for `B 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` ? Certainly without the ambiguity I'm suggesting, this problem is easily solvable with an inclusive prefix sum on `B`.

Comment: first querstion: not difference, and your second question I forget to mention..it won't happen,array A is "sorted" to guarantee that. I feel that prefix sum would be a solution but I can't make sense of it..I am not used to think about this kind of parallel algorithm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach.

Due to the ambiguity of your shifting (`0, 1, 0, 1`, `0, 1, 1, 1` and `0, 1, 0 ,0` all produce the same data offset pattern, for example) it's not possible to just create a prefix sum of the shift pattern to produce the relative offset at each position.  An observation we can make, however, is that a valid offset pattern will be created if each zero in the shift pattern gets replaced by the first non-zero shift value to its left:

```
0, 1, 0, 0   (shift pattern)
0, 1, 1, 1   (offset pattern)
```

or

```
0, 2, 0, 2   (shift pattern)
0, 2, 2, 2   (offset pattern)
```

So how to do this?  Let's assume we have the second test case shift pattern:

```
      0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0
```

Our desired offset pattern would be:

```
      0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

1. for a given shift pattern, create a binary value, where each bit is one if the value at the corresponding index into the shift pattern is zero, and zero otherwise.  We can use a [warp vote](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) instruction, called `__ballot()` for this.  Each lane will get the same value from the ballot:

   ```
     1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  (this is a single binary 8-bit value in this case)
   ```
2. Each warp lane will now take this value, and add a value to it which has a 1 bit at the warp lane position.  Using lane 1 for the remainder of the example:

   ```
   + 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  (the only 1 bit in this value will be at the lane index)
   = 1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1
   ```
3. We now take the result of step 2, and bitwise exclusive-OR with the result from step 1:

   ```
   = 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
   ```
4. We now count the number of 1 bits in this value (there is a `__popc()` [intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT) for this), and subtract one from the result.  So for the lane 1 example above, the result of this step would be `2`, since there are 3 bits set.  This gives use the distance to the first value to our left that is non-zero in the original shift pattern.  So for the lane 1 example, the first non-zero value to the left of lane 1 is 2 lanes higher, i.e. lane 3.
5. For each lane, we use the result of step 4 to grab the appropriate offset value for that lane.  We can process all lanes at once using a `__shfl_down()` [warp shuffle](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) instruction.

   ```
     0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
   ```

   Thus producing our desired "offset pattern".

Once we have the desired offset pattern, the process of having each warp lane use its offset value to appropriately shift its data item is straightforward.

Here is a fully worked example, using your 3 test cases.  Steps 1-4 above are contained in the `__device__` function `mydelta`.  The remainder of the kernel is performing the step 5 shuffle, appropriately indexing into the data, and copying the data.  Due to the usage of the warp shuffle instructions, we must compile this for a cc3.0 or higher GPU. (However, it would not be difficult to replace the warp shuffle instructions with other indexing code that would allow operation on cc2.0 or greater devices.)  Also, due to the various intrinsics used, this function cannot work for more than 32 data items, but that was a prerequisite condition stated in your question.

```
$ cat t475.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#define DSIZE 8

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


__device__ int mydelta(const int shift){
  unsigned nz = __ballot(shift == 0);
  unsigned mylane = (threadIdx.x & 31);
  unsigned lanebit = 1<<mylane;
  unsigned temp = nz + lanebit;
  temp = nz ^ temp;
  unsigned delta = __popc(temp);
  return delta-1;
}
__global__ void mykernel(const int *data, const unsigned *shift, int *result, const int limit){ // limit <= 32
  if (threadIdx.x < limit){
    unsigned lshift = shift[(limit - 1) - threadIdx.x];
    unsigned delta = mydelta(lshift);
    unsigned myshift = __shfl_down(lshift, delta);
    myshift = __shfl(myshift, ((limit -1) - threadIdx.x)); // reverse offset pattern
    result[threadIdx.x] = 0;
    if ((myshift + threadIdx.x) < limit)
    result[threadIdx.x + myshift] = data[threadIdx.x];
  }
}

int main(){
  int A[DSIZE]         = {3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5};
  unsigned tc1B[DSIZE] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  unsigned tc2B[DSIZE] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0};
  unsigned tc3B[DSIZE] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};

  int *d_data, *d_result, *h_result;
  unsigned *d_shift;
  h_result = (int *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  if (h_result == NULL) { printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_shift, DSIZE*sizeof(unsigned));
  cudaMalloc(&d_result, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, A, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_shift, tc1B, DSIZE*sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyH2D fail");
  mykernel<<<1,32>>>(d_data, d_shift, d_result, DSIZE);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyD2H fail");
  printf("index: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", i);
  printf("\nA:     ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", A[i]);
  printf("\ntc1 B: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", tc1B[i]);
  printf("\ntc1 C: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", h_result[i]);
  cudaMemcpy(d_shift, tc2B, DSIZE*sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyH2D fail");
  mykernel<<<1,32>>>(d_data, d_shift, d_result, DSIZE);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyD2H fail");
  printf("\ntc2 B: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", tc2B[i]);
  printf("\ntc2 C: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", h_result[i]);
  cudaMemcpy(d_shift, tc3B, DSIZE*sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyH2D fail");
  mykernel<<<1,32>>>(d_data, d_shift, d_result, DSIZE);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
  cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMempcyD2H fail");
  printf("\ntc3 B: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", tc3B[i]);
  printf("\ntc2 C: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    printf("%d, ", h_result[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t475 t475.cu
$ ./t475
index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
A:     3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5,
tc1 B: 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
tc1 C: 3, 0, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3,
tc2 B: 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
tc2 C: 3, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2,
tc3 B: 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
tc2 C: 3, 0, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3,
$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort!